# C# reflection, get ref return type from MethodInfo.Invoke

Tags: c#, generics, reflection

I use a static library class which has a static generic function, with `where T : struct` clause.

Also, this function returns `ref T`.

I wanted to use `System.Type` as parameter to invoke this generic function, so made a helper function which uses reflection.

```
public static object MyFunction(System.Type t, object[] parameters)
{
    var name = nameof(MyStaticLibraryClass.RefReturnStaticMethod);
    var method = typeof(MyStaticLibraryClass).GetMethod(name, BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static);
    var generic = method.MakeGenericMethod(someType);
    object ret = generic.Invoke(null, parameters);
    return ret;
}
```

Unfortunately when I use return value `ret`, it's value type rather than reference to that struct object.

While debugging, I found out that `ret` is marked as ByRef type of `t`.

So the question is, how do I use this `object ret` as ref type?
Seems like `return ref ret` doesn't work...

Comment: Please provide code which compiles. For example `params` is a reserved keyword.

Comment: @PeterCsala The code is just an simple abstraction of original one, but anyway edited.